# JAX-RS needs to check Authorization only

Tags: jquery, security, tomcat, jax-rs

We have a cakephp app that makes Ajax calls to get data and post back to a Jax-RS webservice (in development).

Authentication within cakephp is done against an LDAP server
Authorization will be done by the Web service for each given request
By nature the web service  is stateless and sessionless
Users,Permissions,Roles will be stored in a Table in the DB.

Question is what options are available for authorizing users. 
Can we use inbuilt JDBC Realm or Datasource realm for authorizing users (remember no password will be stored or sent as we are not doing authentication)

What is the best way to secure the webservice so that only requests from the cakephp app
are honored and others dropped

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your circumstance, you may simply limit requests to the machine(s) running the PHP application. This could be done with just firewall configuration.

Otherwise, assuming you're packaging the application as WAR, you can use the usual methods of securing a web application. Your JAX-RS resources can also have a [`SecurityContext`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) injected with `@Context` for more fine-grained control (e.g. obtain the principal; see also `@RolesAllowed`, `@DenyAll`, `@PermitAll`).

Comment: For the SecurityContext, do I need to a Realm (Tomcat) ?